# Routing works different on development and production server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a url parameter that sends a unique id to the other page. It works right on development server.

When I run the live on production server, it sometimes runs wrong. I am sending the same ID but from the second page it is sometimes getting random ID instead of getting the ID that I am sending.

Since it works right on development, I can't figure out what is wrong.

I appreciate if you guys can help me!

Comment: By the way, it mostly works right at first click. However,  when I wait on the page 4-5 minutes then click on the button, it is getting different ID.

Comment: What else is in your production pipeline?  Do you have a misconfigured caching server?

Comment: Also, are you using static or class variables to cache the ID?  If so, you're experiencing what happens when more than one person uses the app.

Comment: I am setting the id_finder as static int.

Comment: Berin Loritsch I think that is what it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I send the parameter
    
    
                
                    '
                        Text="Details">

Then I am getting it from another page

```
 id_finder = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID_FINDER"]);
```

All above works right

Then I am sending it from this second page to third page as

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Forms/StatusComment.aspx?id_chk=" + id_finder + "&id_chk_del=0&id_chk_inc=0&is_caused=" + hiddenis_caused.Value);
```

Then getting it from third page as

```
id_chk = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id_chk"]);
```

Comment: Here is how I send the parameter   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server"
                        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("req_id", "~/Existing_Requests/submitted_requests.aspx?ID_FINDER={0}") %>'
                        Text="Details"></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>